# How to dismiss keyboard on a textfield when a user triggers an action sheet and dismisses it?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a UITextField that conforms to `UITextFieldDelegate`

`@IBOutlet weak var myCoolTextField: UITextField!`

I also have a button that triggers an action sheet.

```
@IBAction func myCoolButton(sender: UIButton) {
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey", message: "Hey there", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
  let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
  alert.addAction(dismissAction)
  self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

If a user is in the middle of editing `myCoolTextField`, they can tap `myCoolButton` which dismisses the keyboard for editing `myCoolTextField` and then the UIAlertController takes over with the action sheet. When the user dismisses the alert, the keyboard automatically pops up again and takes the user back to editing `myCoolTextField`.

How would I go about preventing this from happening? If the user taps `myCoolButton` while in the middle of editing `myCoolTextField` and then dismisses the alert, I don't want `myCoolTextField` to automatically go back into edit mode.

I have the regular old `textFieldShouldReturn` and `touchesBegan` methods which work for tapping anywhere else on the screen. I've tried putting methods to end the editing of `myCoolTextField` in the presenting of the action sheet's completion handler but it doesn't do anything since by that time the keyboard and text field are temporarily not active. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dismiss the keyboard with the `resignFirstResponder` method:

```
@IBAction func myCoolButton(sender: UIButton) {
  myCoolTextField.resignFirstResponder()
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey", message: "Hey there", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
  let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
  alert.addAction(dismissAction)
  self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I should have thought of this. Thanks.